# I am trying to prove this as a tautology , contradiction without using a truth table.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is the statement form $((\lnot p \wedge q)\wedge (q \vee r))\wedge (\lnot q \wedge r)$ a tautology, contradiction
or neither? I know it's simple just can't get started.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  If you look carefully you have lots of expressions AND other expressions (together with the occasional OR).  Among other things you have $q$ and $\sim q$, so. . . ?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a matter of calculating, systematically using the rules of propositional logic:

\begin{align}
& ((\lnot p \land q) \land (q \lor r)) \land (\lnot q \land r) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"leave out unnecessary parentheses, since $\;\land\;$ is associative, three times"} \\
& \lnot p \land q \land (q \lor r) \land \lnot q \land r \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"exchange two conjuncts, since $\;\land\;$ is symmetric"} \\
& \lnot p \land q \land \lnot q \land (q \lor r) \land r \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"simplify using contradiction, i.e., $\;\phi \land \lnot \phi \;\equiv\; \text{false}\;$"} \\
& \lnot p \land \text{false} \land (q \lor r) \land r \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"simplify using $\;\phi \land \text{false} \;\equiv\; \text{false}\;$, and its symmetric version"} \\
& \text{false} \\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Contradiction. Simply you have $\neg q$ and q 
$((\neg p \wedge q)\wedge(q \vee r))\wedge(\neg q \wedge r)=
(\neg p \wedge q)\wedge(\neg q \wedge r)=
(q\wedge\neg q)\wedge(~p\wedge r)=$contradiction

EDITED (using only basic laws)
$((\neg p \wedge q)\wedge(q \vee r))\wedge(\neg q \wedge r)=^{1}
(\neg p \wedge q)\wedge ((\neg q\wedge r \wedge q)\vee (r\wedge \neg q\wedge r))=^{2}$
$(\neg p \wedge q)\wedge (r\wedge \neg q)=\neg p \wedge q\wedge r\wedge \neg q=
(\neg q \wedge q)\wedge (r\wedge \neg p )=^{3}CONTRADICTION
$

1. This comes from the law: $A\wedge (B\vee C)=(A\wedge B)\vee (A\wedge B)$, when $A=(\neg q \wedge r)$, $B=q$ and $C=r$.
2. This comes from $(\neg q\wedge r \wedge q)=(\neg q \wedge q)$ is always false. So the other statement in the disjunction must be true. I mean, you have 
   $((\neg q\wedge r \wedge q)\vee (r\wedge \neg q\wedge r))=(false)\vee (r\wedge \neg q\wedge r)=(r\wedge \neg q\wedge r)$

   I also use $(r\wedge \neg q\wedge r)=(r\wedge \neg q)$
3. We have q and $\neg q$

Comment: Should (q ^ ~q) ^ (p ^ r) actually be  (q ^ ~q) ^ (~p ^r) and therefore just a matter of associative and commutative realignment to achieve a contradiction?

Comment: See edits and think about it please. Really i cant explain it more ;)